# Short story with pianist who has to sacrifice too-heavy piano

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, music

I'm looking a story I read as a teen back in the seventies, in an anthology no doubt.

The plot point that sticks with me is this: a young pianist who is moving off-world has to sacrifice the piano, which is too heavy for the ship to carry.

I've Googled around but haven't found it. Does the story ring any bells?

Comment: Thanks for covering most of the common clues.  Did you read this story in English?  Where were you at the time (what country)?  Do you remember anything about the author?  Male or female?  Well known or unknown?  Was it set on Earth, an alien planet, or an imaginary world?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete. … See also [our guidance](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Passage for Piano](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57208) by Frank Herbert.

The main protagonist is Margaret Hatchell:

> Had some cosmic crystal gazer suggested to Margaret Hatchell that she would try to smuggle a concert grand piano onto the colony spaceship, she would have been shocked. Here she was at home in her kitchen on a hot summer afternoon, worried about how to squeeze ounces into her family's meager weight allowance for the trip - and the piano weighed more than half a ton.

They are emigrating to *Planet C*. The pianist is Margaret's son David who is blind. In the end:

> David works out they can take the harp and keyboard from the piano and have a new case made when they reach Planet C.

Comment: That's it! Somehow I didn't consider Herbert. I ordered the collection, so I won't read the spoiler yet :-) thank you so much @John Rennie